# Reference variable with computed name

Tags: javascript, variables, eval

I'm looking to access a variable by using a variable name dynamically computed at runtime.  Example code:

```
var firstSecond = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var tempDatabase = 'first';
var tempTable = 'Second';
var copyArray = MAGIC(tempDatabase + tempTable);
```

`copyArray` should be the array: `['a', 'b', 'c']`.  Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. `copyArray` is equal to `"firstSecond"` not an array.

Comment: No. You cannot access local variables by name in JavaScript, except by evil. And you cannot copy arrays by assignment. This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Have you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript ?

Comment: `MAGIC = eval`, but you really should not. Store all the possible arrays in an object, and reference them by a dynamic property name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an object:

```
var o = {firstSecond: ['a', 'b', 'c']}
var tempDatabase = 'first';
var tempTable = 'Second';
var copyArray = o[tempDatabase + tempTable];

document.write(copyArray)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pdt3sse7/

Comment: Thanks. That worked!